# Numbering theorems in decimals instead of whole numbers

Tags: numbering, theorems, amsthm

Please,theorems are numbered in whole numbers like 1,2 ...., but I want it to be  numbered in decimals like 1.0,1.1...
How do I achieve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing how you currently number your theorems. Please also clarify: Is the `1` in `1.0`, `1.1` and `1.2` the chapter/section number of the chaper/section the theomrems are in or does it have another meaning?

Answer (score 1):

If the "decimals" are referred to chapter or section counter, you can specify a parent counter:

```
\newtheorem{yourtheorem}{Theorem}[name-of-counter]
```

A MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{yourthrm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{the first section}
\begin{yourthrm}
    the first theorem
\end{yourthrm}
\begin{yourthrm}
    the second theorem
\end{yourthrm}

\section{the second section}
\begin{yourthrm}
    the third theorem
\end{yourthrm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But it can also be a counter of your liking:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{0}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{yourthrm}{Theorem}[mycounter]

\begin{document}

\begin{yourthrm}
    the first theorem
\end{yourthrm}
(counter increase here) \stepcounter{mycounter}
\begin{yourthrm}
    the second theorem
\end{yourthrm}
\begin{yourthrm}
    the third theorem
\end{yourthrm}
(counter increase here) \stepcounter{mycounter}
\begin{yourthrm}
    the fourth theorem
\end{yourthrm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot, I think this will do it

Comment: You are welcome! remember also to [upvote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up)/[accept](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) the answers that helped you the most ;)
On this site, it is the preferred way to show appreciation